# How to use a string as a primary key with Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code:

```
Pult.Zone = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  authoritative: DS.attr('boolean'),
  user_id: DS.attr('number'),
  rulesets: DS.hasMany('Pult.Ruleset')
});

Pult.RESTAdapter.map('Pult.Zone', {
  primaryKey: 'name',
  rulesets: { key: 'rulesetIds' }
});
```

However, it doesn't seem like is picking up on the primary key correctly. I have rendered a list of all zones.

Here's a test case:

```
zones = Pult.store.findAll(Pult.Zone);
zones.get('length'); // Returns 10
zones = Pult.store.findAll(Pult.Zone);
zones.get('length'); // Returns 20
```

So every time I load zones from the server, it adds them to the local list, since it does not recognize them as already existing. Any way to fix this, or will I have to try to mock up some surrogate keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After upgrading to [Ember Data 1.0.0 Beta 2](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/09/04/ember-data-1-0-beta-2-released.html), I found a solution that works:

```
App.Zone = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  user_id: DS.attr('number'),
});

App.ZoneSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(type, hash, property) {
    // Ember Data use the zone name as the ID.
    hash.id = hash.name;

    // Delegate to any type-specific normalizations.
    return this._super(type, hash, property);
  }
});
```